# Checkout a specific file from git repository

Tags: git

I have a `git repo` with `several folders` in it

I want to checkout only 1 folder,and not all of them

What is the command for it ?

Comment: "git clone subdir" didnt work?

Answer (score 2):

You can checkout any file or folder to wherever you like. E.g. If your current repository has a folder `src/main/java` you can do a

```
git --work-tree=/tmp/someCheckout checkout -- src/main/java
```

This will checkout the folder `src/main/java` to the directory `/tmp/someCheckout`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run `git checkout path/to/folder/` this will checkout all files inside the selected folder.
You add files using `git add path/to/folder/` to add all files inside the specified folder with all sub-folder files.